# How to debug multiple web projects on single IIS application pool?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a solution with two web ASP MVC 4.6.1 projects that deploy to the same website/application pool. However, when I try to debug the non-primary project by attaching to the w3wp process, I cannot hit any breakpoints (no symbols loaded for this document error) for controllers that reside in the secondary project. How can I debug the secondary project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug the secondary project, you need to Add the .PDB files of the secondary project DLL in the bin folder.

Comment: hmm, the secondary project DLL .PDB files are in the bin of the application deploy folder.

Comment: hmm, check once configuration is not set to Release when you started the debugger, if yes change it to debug

Comment: Perfect, that was the issue. Configurations are now aligned.